# How to optimize android app for battery usage

Tags: android, optimization, battery

I created an application which runs on background in every 3 minutes and do some calculation and update data on sqlite database.my app is consuming more battery after installing this app.
so can you please update me how to create app for optimization battery life.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple: don't do things that are not needed.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

Comment: Also use the app lifecycle functions properly!!!

Comment: Are you creating a network connection when you are running in the background? That would drain the battery quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes offcourse it is possible, your application is draining battery because you are running your service all the time but instead of that
....................................................................................................................
The best practice is to 
create a AlarmManager context using PendingIntent, Now for every 3 min set an alarm.
create a BroadcastReceiver which receives alarm after every 3 minutes.
NOW....
from that Receiver start your service do calculations on that service and save it into database. after saving clear() all the data of intents, database  objects and also close the database connections.
and after doing all these things call stopService() to stop your service immediately.
This makes your application to startService() only after every 3 mins and after doing all calculations it stops service.
check with this and i am sure you will not get any problem regarding battery because your service will run for max 2 secs on every 3 mins :)

Comment: or you are stopping and starting it again and again?

Comment: thats the reason your app is taking more battery

Comment: @Rahul: rewrite you answer a bit so that it contains the results of the discussion in the comments, and rephrase it a bit so that is is more an answer and do not start with "... but first you have to tell me..."